# Fastest way to insert record in multiple table connected with id

Tags: mysql, database, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Let's say I have the below schema. country -> states -> district -> village.
I understand in the real scenario there won't be an auto-increment id for country states etc.
But let's assume that we have the below scenario.

I am using MySQL as a database.

[image]

these all tables are dependent on the previous table id.
for example, once the countryId is generated that would be used in state table, once stateId is generated that would be used in the district table and so on.

That's the real problem. In a crude way, I can add country object and insert in country table. Get the auto-generated country id and insert the record in state table and so on.

If I have 100 countries to insert then there will be billions of records to be inserted in the village table and the crude way is going to be a terrible way to do it.

I am looking for the fastest way to do it.
I am open for spring boot, JPA, and some other way also.

Any link, suggestion, idea is welocme.

Comment: You'll need to use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, or its equivalent in the calling language/ORM. After you insert a country, this will contain the country ID, which you can use as the FK in the `State` records. And after you insert a state, it will contain the state ID, which you can use in the `District` records.

Comment: If you want all this to be automated, use an ORM.

Comment: `I understand in the real scenario there won't be an auto-increment id for country states etc.` - in which case, you understand more than I do.

Comment: Terrifyingly, there's approximately 8 billion people on this planet. But even so, if everyone lived in a village, and there were a billion villages, that would mean an average of 8 people per village. I suspect your arithmetic is off somewhere.

Comment: @Strawberry Ok, I agree my arithmetic is off somewhere, Thanks for letting me know. That is not a real example. I have a similar problem that I am trying to solve. I can put the original table and data so I just tried creating a similar situation. If you could help me crack the problem that would be great